# joining DataFrames in spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I would like joing two dataframes: edges and selectedComponent by two keys using `or` function

```
 val selectedComponent = hiveContext.sql(s"""select * from $tableWithComponents
         |where component=$component""".stripMargin)
```

but not this way

```
val theSelectedComponentEdges = hiveContext.sql(
  s"""select * from $tableWithComponents a join $edges b where (b.src=a.id or b.dst=a.id)""")
```

but using join function

```
edges.join(selectedComponent, edges("src")===selectedComponent("id"))
```

but I am not sure how I supposed to using here "or".

Anyone can help me :-)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
edges.join(selectedComponent, (edges("src")===selectedComponent("id")) ||  (edges("dst")===selectedComponent("id")))
```

Comment: correct, but you got the column names mixed up a bit - should be `(edges("src")===selectedComponent("id")) ||  (edges("dst")===selectedComponent("id"))`

Comment: I checked that    `val a = edges.join(selectedComponent, edges("src")===selectedComponent("id")) //
    val b = edges.join(selectedComponent, edges("dst")===selectedComponent("id")) //
    val theSelectedComponentEdges = a.unionAll(b)` and it is faster, is it the same?

Comment: It is the same result, but it is true that catalyst messes up joins with complex join expression (it often does a cartesian product...). But I see that as an issues of catalyst, and your optimisation, while valid for the moment, is (hopefully) not future-proof. Edit: you should actually check when `src == dst`, you will have duplicate in your implementation, but (I think) not in the first one.